# Is this path RESTful?

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have a doubt

Is this path restful?

> api/Cars/Sources

Sources exist in the context of Cars.
Imagine that I have this sources:

> Source1 : name = source1 , Source2: name = source2

And then in my cars I have:

> Car1: name =car1, sourceName = source1
>
> Car2: name =car2, sourceName = source2

So, my path is rest or should be separated?

Comment: it all depend on how the endpoint  of your API server is setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers.  See [REST: I Don't Think it Means What You Think it Does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM), by Stefan Tilkov (2014).

The key idea: in [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), the client follows links provided by the server, rather than constructing links described in documentation.